# Why do I get two extra divs displayed on my web page?

Tags: css, html

I just built a page with literally nothing on it but a div containing one header and two paragraphs. I put a border around the div in CSS.  When I browse to the page the div and paragraphs have the border and there are two empty bordered "divs" above it all.
See for yourself:  https://ext.careersourcebroward.com/ITAList/

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div {
            width:60%;
            border:5px double blue;
            text-align:center;
            border-radius:25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>ITA List</h1>
        <p>This is the ITA List</p>
        <p>There will be a table with the Programs listed below.</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I encountered this same issue with another existing web site I worked on yesterday.  Totally different web site.  I added an inline css to the div to change the border color to red.  The two phantom divs above it remained blue.

Comment: Styling the element div it's too global, you should add a class to your div and style that class

Comment: These div's are added by webform and are meant to be hidden by you. As you had defined a general css rule which made border 5px and blue for all divs that's why you got those divs prominent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this style:

```
.aspNetHidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That did solve the problem.  I still don't know what caused the problem.  I've never seen this behavior before.

Answer (score 1):

The two extra divs has the class of "aspNetHidden", which was generated from your server side code. Based on the class of these divs, they were supposed to be hidden. But since you didn't load any css/sytle rules to define such behavior, they were treated as regular divs, which were overridden by you own css rule.

Comment: "aspNetHidden" generated by what server side code? I just threw that page together in 30 seconds and added no code to the code behind page. I saw them in the "view page source."  I've made countless pages like this and have only seen this happen in the last two days.  I'll add the display: none; as kblok suggests.

Answer (score 1):

These div's are added by ASP.NET Web Form and are meant to be hidden by you. As you have defined a general css rule for all div's. It will apply it to all div's regardless of Web Form generated divs or your created div's.

```
 <style>
    div {
        width:60%;
        border:5px double blue;
        text-align:center;
        border-radius:25px;
    }
</style>
```

As @Kblob suggested you can create a css rule which will hide all ASP.NET Web Form created div's with class name aspNetHidden. To be on save side in future you can create css classes for divs and apply those classes to your required divs only.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just do that from now on.  Now that I know why it's happening, it's easily handled.  Thank you.